# JFrame checkbox data stored in a variable. How can I input this into a mysql query?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, variables, jframe

I have 2 checkbox options to allow a user to select how many nights they want to stay on the booking form.

[[image: Picture of checkboxes]**strong text**

Once all of the customer details have been added, such as name, address, email..., I am inputting these into a mysql workbench database to be stored.

Because I have two checkbox options for the nights selected section, which will be stored in one variable depending on what the user selects, how am I able to input this into my database? The checkboxes are called 2 different names as I am unable to call them the same thing. How can I use the variable later on in the code to find what the user selects.

Get text from variable strings for the sql query

[image: Get text from variable strings for the sql query]

Sorry if this doesnt make any sense, I am new to this so please ask if you need any more clarification :)

my sql query so far

[image: my sql query so far]

As you can see from this image, the other variables are able to be input, but I cant figure out how to get the nightsChosen one to work.

Comment: that is no prepared statements with parameters that is only a concatinated string. But it  will be simpler when you post text instead of images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you should address:

- to get the value of the check box, use the isSelected() method on the check box instance. It'll return **true** if the box is checked. Since they're different instances, you know which one is for 7 days and which is for 14 so depending on which one is checked, you'll know the value to use.
- from a UX perspective, if these choices are mutually exclusive (you can only pick 7 or 14 days, never both), you should use radio buttons rather than checkboxes.
- in your SQL query, you're using a prepared statement (which is good). But you're still forming the sql by manually forming the string. This would leave you open to a SQL injection attack. The way you should do it is by using placeholder values in the sql string and then binding the variables to the placeholders. For instance:

  PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from mytable where id = ?");
  stmt.setInt(1, yourVariable);
- Rather than post images showing your code, in the future, please include the text in the question itself when posting to StackOverflow. It makes the questions more searchable and it enables the community to more easily see/try your code.